# Synaptic corrupted, not able to install anything even from terminal

Tags: synaptic

my synaptic is not working. whenever i open it, i find that it is corrupted and asks me to run `dpkg ---configure -a` whenever i run it on root terminal, it starts downloading 1 GB files and there is written `"48h 22m left"` or something like that. i don't want to download that file. please help

Comment: If it's asking for you to run that command - what had you done previously that didn't complete? It might help to see the error messages you get.

Comment: Could you please add the complete output. Edit your question.

Comment: @Elfy I was trying to install a software.....forgot its name. when its was installing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you stopped the process of installing/upgrading prematurely, so package manager wants to correct the situation. You have run what it says: "sudo dpkg --configure -a". After that completes, everything will probably be OK. If the problem persists post the console output here.

Comment: i run it, but after that i have to download a BIG file and i dont want to download it. please help dear @kaan